# error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory when trying to clone on windows

Tags: windows, git, git-clone

I am trying to clone a remote repository on Windows, but when I did this:

```
git clone git@github.com:organization/xxx.git
```

I got this error:

```
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't have ssh installed (or don't have it within your search path).

You can clone from github via http, too:

```
git clone http://github.com/organization/xxx
```

Comment: when googling, i read that there is easier way in case i used `cygwin` (which is my case).

Comment: In this case, just install the ssh package. It's been a while since I worked with cygwin, but I think you just need to restart the setup and select the ssh package.

Comment: msysgit-- another alternative.

Answer (score 70):

Check if you have installed `ssh-client`. **This solves the problem on docker images, even when ssh keys are present**.

On Debian images:

```
apt-get install openssh-client
```

On Alpine images:

```
apk add openssh-client
```

Comment: The correct package name is `openssh-client`

Comment: and `RUN apk add openssh-client` works on alpine image builds

Answer (score 8):

Most likely your `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` is referencing the incorrect public key.

Try:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /home/murphyslaw/.ssh/your-key.id_rsa
```

then

```
git clone git@github.com:organization/xxx.git
```

Comment: Had the same error message but a different cause, 'ssh' missing from PATH;  export GIT_SSH_COMMAND=/usr/bin/ssh fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I am aware that it is an old topic, but having this problem recently, I want to bring here what I resolve my issue.

---

You might have this error on these conditions :

- You use a URL like this : `git@github.com:organization/repo.git`
- And you run a kind of command like this directly : `git clone git@github.com/xxxxx.git` whereas you don't have ssh client (or it is not present on path)
- Or you have an ssh client installed (and `git clone xxx.git` work fine on direct command line) but when you run the same kind of command through a shell script file

---

Here, I assume that you don't want to change protocol `ssh git@` to `http://`
(`git@github.com:organization/repo.git` -> `http://github.com/organization/repo.git`), like my case, cause I needed the `ssh` format.

---

So,

- If you do not have ssh client, first of all, you need to install it
- If you have this error only when you execute it through a script, then you need to set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` variable with your public ssh key, in front of your git command, like this :

> `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="/usr/bin/ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" git pull`

(Feel free to change it depending on your context)

Comment: Perfect answer, my bash script is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue right after my antivirus moved the cygwin ssh binary to virus vault, and restored it after.

Symptoms:

- SSH seems properly installed
- SSH can be run from command line without problem

Another option before reinstalling ssh in this particular case: check the `ssh` command permissions

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/ssh.exe
----rwxrwx+
$ chmod 770 /usr/bin/ssh.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error on the `Alpine` container in the `CI-CD` pipeline. I have added `openssh` package and it worked.

`RUN apk add --no-cache git openssh`

Answer (score 0):

You can try these as well

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/identity_file
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/identity_file
```

Answer (score 0):

It so happened in my case that the new pair of ssh keys linked with my git account were not accessible.

I had to `sudo chmod 777 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.*` to resolve the issue.